# Ordering while still maintaining groups with MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hope this is possible-

Have a table like so:

```
Car_ID    Brand    Model      Year
----------------------------------
   1      Ford      Focus       2012
   1      Ford      Mustang     1992
   2      Toyota    Yaris       2005
   3      BMW       1s          1995
   4      VW        Polo        2010
   4      VW        Golf        2002
   4      VW        Beetle      2007
```

And want it ordering like this:

```
Car_ID    Brand    Model      Year
----------------------------------
   1      Ford      Focus       2012
   1      Ford      Mustang     1992

   4      VW        Polo        2010
   4      VW        Beetle      2007
   4      VW        Golf        2002

   2      Toyota    Yaris       2005

   3      BMW       1s          1995
```

- So the brand with the newest model is first, followed by the rest of
  the brand's models in order of newest.
- Next is the brand with the second newest model and the rest of cars
  of that brand, newest first
- And so on.

Any ideas if this can be done?

--ANSWER-- - my answer was wrong, will post back when I test some more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql>     SELECT cars.*
    -> 
    ->       FROM cars
    ->       JOIN ( SELECT Name_ID, MAX(Year) AS max_year 
    ->              FROM cars 
    ->              GROUP BY Name_ID )
    ->         AS dt_max
    ->      USING (Name_ID)
    -> 
    ->   ORDER BY max_year DESC, Name_ID, Year DESC;
+---------+--------+---------+------+
| Name_ID | Brand  | Model   | Year |
+---------+--------+---------+------+
|       1 | Ford   | Focus   | 2012 |
|       1 | Ford   | Mustang | 1992 |
|       4 | VW     | Polo    | 2010 |
|       4 | VW     | Beetle  | 2007 |
|       4 | VW     | Golf    | 2002 |
|       2 | Toyota | Yaris   | 2005 |
|       3 | BMW    | 1s      | 1995 |
+---------+--------+---------+------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with this answer I posted 2 days ago? There's a reason no one else has provided an answer.

Comment: Sorry I didn't comment back sooner. Your answer was abolutely perfect, thank you for taking the time to help me!